# Matplotlib draw Spline from multiple points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have array points

```
nodes = [(1, 2), (6, 15), (10, 6), (10, 3), (3, 7)]
```

And now, I need draw `Spline` passing through the points. You can see image result
[image]

But I don't know how to draw with `matplotlib.pyplot`. Help me

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So , the right piece of code is:

```
from __future__ import division
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate


nodes = np.array( [ [1, 2], [6, 15], [10, 6], [10, 3], [3, 7] ] )

x = nodes[:,0]
y = nodes[:,1]

tck,u     = interpolate.splprep( [x,y] ,s = 0 )
xnew,ynew = interpolate.splev( np.linspace( 0, 1, 100 ), tck,der = 0)

plt.plot( x,y,'o' , xnew ,ynew )
plt.legend( [ 'data' , 'spline'] )
plt.axis( [ x.min() - 1 , x.max() + 1 , y.min() - 1 , y.max() + 2 ] )
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but it's not what I want. This is the image I have when using matplotlib according to your code: http://i.imgur.com/Cz7MnMU.png . But in the order of the coordinates of points, it should be like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj6Eh.png

Comment: With best you came up, I think it's `polilyne`, not `Spline`, `Spline` like here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj6Eh.png

Comment: @Duc Tran: The splprep is used to find the b-spline as stated here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splprep.html.  Check  my update!

Comment: Hi, you missed out the `s=0` in the `splprep()` call on your last bit of code, which is why the spline misses the point in the bottom right and doesn't quite match the OP's desired output.  I think the answer could probably use a little editing now, too - you can move the code from "best you came up", edit in the code above the last image and then remove all the stuff before "UPDATE" as it doesn't really answer the original question.

Comment: You should remove the line `from __future__ import division` or move it to the top, otherwise you get an error

Comment: @ hitzg:Thanks!I missed that too!