# Matplotlib Draw Spline from 3 points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I draw `Spline` follow post: [Matplotlib draw Spline from multiple points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837854/matplotlib-draw-spline-from-multiple-points)

But when I draw `Spline` from 3 points

```
from __future__ import division
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate


nodes = np.array( [ [1, 2], [6, 15], [10, 6] ] )

x = nodes[:,0]
y = nodes[:,1]

tck,u     = interpolate.splprep( [x,y] ,s = 0 )
xnew,ynew = interpolate.splev( np.linspace( 0, 1, 100 ), tck,der = 0)

plt.plot( x,y,'o' , xnew ,ynew )
plt.legend( [ 'data' , 'spline'] )
plt.axis( [ x.min() - 1 , x.max() + 1 , y.min() - 1 , y.max() + 2 ] )
plt.show()
```

I get error

```
raise TypeError('m > k must hold')
TypeError: m > k must hold
```

So, help me draw Spline from 3 points :(

Comment: More of a tip than anything else, you should try to *understand* code people give you, not just use it blindly, and hence have to come running back when something breaks.  Spline fitting is not a new art - plenty of resources for understanding it out there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number of points (m) must be greater than the degree of the spline (k).    According to the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splprep.html), the default degree is k = 3. Since you have three points, the degree needs to be set to 2 by changing the following line:

```
tck,u = interpolate.splprep( [x,y], k = 2)
```

[image: 3 point spline]

Comment: I am confused. I think 3 points still can produce a cubic spline. but k=2 will only generate a 2nd order spline ?

Comment: @kevin that is not true